# WSDL to Grails 2.5 domain classes

Tags: grails, soap, wsdl, grails-domain-class, wsdl2java

What is the easiest way to generate Grails 2.5 domain classes from WSDL?

The grails-cxf-client plugin looks like it uses wsdl2java to create java classes, but I need Grails domain classes.

I could always just redo the java files as domain classes, but I don't know if that will break the grails-cxf-client.